# Having trouble scraping this site

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a site here at work and I am having trouble with an error code . Here is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "https://reddit.com" #just an example
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(html).text, 'html.parser')
rootDiv=soup.find('div',attrs={'id':'root'})
if(rootDiv):
   targetdivs=rootDiv.find('div',attrs={'class':'box-bottom'})
   for targetDiv in targetdivs:
       span=targetdivs.find('span',attrs={'class':'box-bottom-offline'})
       if(span):
           print(span.text)
```

And this is a snip of what I'm trying to scrape circled in Red.

After I run the code I get the error:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Any advice will be greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely in the html, **'class':'box-bottom'** only appear **once**, that is also why the error says *"object is not iterable"*, that basically means **targetDiv is not an array** that you can loop.

just try

```py
print(targetdivs)
```

after

```py
targetdivs=rootDiv.find('div',attrs={'class':'box-bottom'})
```

then you'll get your answer, hope this helps

Comment: I still am having issues with this code, it is still returning NONE